# Is it possible to learn more then 1 skill in a single battle?

Tags: digimon-world

I'm actually fighting Giromon and multiple guides say about all his 3 ability that the whole game has just 1-2 occasions to get them. Right now I'm having a Andromon who is even capable to learn all 3 of his abilitys.

And since DG Dimension is the 1 of the 1-2 occassions and I'm doubting when the 2nd occassion for the other 2 abilitys will occur, that I have even a mech digimon capable of learning them, I would love to get out of the combat with getting all 3 of them. But I made now allready like 6 fights and never learned more then one of the 3 abilitys.

So is the ability learning per combat limited (to 1)?
Or is it just unlikely that it will be more then 1 (but possible)?

Answer (score 1):

In all the years and countless hours I've poured into this game, periodically returning to play it out of an implicit desire to satisfy nostalgia, I've only ever learnt x1 technique at a time after battle.

In my experience, your digimon ***can only learn one per battle***, and there appears to be no direct or indirect indication that your digimon can learn anymore than that at a given time.

**Aspects that may improve possibilities:**

1. A relatively high brain stat value - it's no surprise that your
   digimon needs to be smart to learn something.
2. Successfully guarding against a given technique - in my experience
   this seems to improve the chances of picking up that technique.

It's unfortunate that the advanced techniques are unlikely to be encountered naturally more than once or twice. It means you are subject to slim possibilities of learning these techniques through brain stat training (since you can't pick up any techniques from tournaments either).

**Giromon's techniques and other opportunities to learn them:**

1. DG Dimension <sup>(Machinedramon - *Back Dimension / Infinity Mountain*)</sup>
2. Delete Program <sup>(none)</sup>
3. Reverse Program <sup>(Tekkamon - *Greyloard's Mansion*)</sup>

Unfortunately, I am unable to provide citations on any of the aforementioned claims as there appears to be no official reference or guide that I'm aware of. These are wholly based on personal experience - an accumulation of hours that extend well into the triple digits.